# httpd.conf for drupal deployment

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, httpd.conf

I am trying to create a multi drupal site in one server. I have placed my drupal like

```
/var/www/html/drupal
/var/www/html/drupal01
/var/www/html/drupal02
```

I cant use subdomains for this appIication and i would like to access each drupal site like `http://www.example.com (/var/www/html/drupal) , http://www.example.com/drupal01 (/var/www/html/drupal01)`

I am able to configure my first drupal instance ie `http://www.example.com`. How can I try access my other drupal instances.

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/rdsadminhelp/">
         RewriteEngine On
         RewriteBase /
         AllowOverride None
         Require all granted
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
         RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</Directory>
```

Comment: Where does your `DocumentRoot` point to ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is VirtualHosts

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example1"
    ServerName www.example.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example2"
    ServerName www.example2.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

The default root path of apache server in ubuntu for the domain name 'localhost' is pointed to the **/var/www/html** folder, that's how you can access the **/var/www/html/your_project** via **http://localhost/your_project**.

You can actually create a virtual host with a domain name of your preference (eg: **your_domain**) for your project folder (eg: **/home/user/projects/your_projec**t) so that you could access the project by visting the local url http://your_domain. This would require adding your domain name to /etc/hosts file and placing and enabling the virtual host configuration file which contains the domain name and the project directory path. More details: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

> I have created a bash script to do this step very easily. You just
>   need to execute the script enter the domain name & project path and it
>   will create the virtual host for you.
>
> **bash script: https://github.com/sudheeshsbabu/VirtualHost**
>
> **Steps to create virtualhost using the bash script: https://www.zyxware.com/articles/5742/virtual-host-creation-using-bash-script**